# Compression class error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, networking, tcp, compression

I've created this simple compression class for a client server TCP data connection and it all looks fine to me with no build errors however I am getting a run time error that I cannot correct. The error I am getting is  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1.

Code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CompressedMessage implements Serializable
{   // this instance variable will store the original, compressed and decompressed message
    private String message;

    public CompressedMessage(String message)
    {   
        // begin by coding this method first - initialise instance variable message with the original message
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {   
        return this.message;

    }

    private boolean punctuationChar(String str)
    {   
        // Hint: check if the last character in the string is a punctuation
        int length = str.length();
        str = str.substring(length -2,length-1);

        if(str.equals(",") || str.equals("!") || str.equals(".") || str.equals("?"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private String getWord(String str)
    {   // Hint: if last character in string is punctuation then remove 

    if(punctuationChar(str)== true)
    {
        //remove punctuation of last char
        str = str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
    }

        return str;
    }


    public void compress()
    {   /* read through section 3 of the practical 5 document 
           to get you started. This is called by the server, 
           have a look at the server code where it is called */ 
        ArrayList<String> newMessage = new ArrayList<String>();


        String[] words = message.split(" ");  

        for (String word : words)  
        {  
            getWord(word);
            //if word has already appeared replace with position of previous word
            if(newMessage.contains(word))
            {
                String str = Integer.toString(newMessage.indexOf(word));
                str = str + " ";
                newMessage.add(str);
            }
            else
            {
                word = word + "";
                newMessage.add(word);
            }

         //if word had a punctuation at the end add it back in
         //System.out.println(word);  
        }  

            this.message = newMessage.toString();
            System.out.println("****************COMPRESSING*****************");
            System.out.println(newMessage);

    }

    public void decompress()
    {   /* read through section 3 of the practical 5 document 
           to get you started. This is called by the client,
           have a look at the client code where it is called */
           ArrayList<String> decompMessage = new ArrayList<String>();

           String[] words = message.split(" ");


           for (String word : words)  
        {  
            getWord(word);

            if(word.substring(0,1).matches("[0-9]"))
            {
              int num = Integer.parseInt(word);
              decompMessage.add(decompMessage.get(num));

            }
            else
            {
                decompMessage.add(word);
            }
        }

        this.message = decompMessage.toString();
        System.out.println("****************DECOMPRESSING*****************");
            System.out.println(decompMessage);  

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1952)
    at CompressedMessage.punctuationChar(CompressedMessage.java:24)
    at CompressedMessage.getWord(CompressedMessage.java:40)
    at CompressedMessage.compress(CompressedMessage.java:61)
    at P5_Server.waitForData(P5_Server.java:72)
    at P5_Server.main(P5_Server.java:159)
```

I have tried changing the way a calculated the strings based on the length() but it didn't reduce the errors.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you `str` is `length 0` (empty string ) or `length 1`? In that case `str = str.substring(length -2,length-1);` will result into exception.

You need to put a length check before performing the substring:

```
    if(length > 1){
        str = str.substring(length-2,length-1);
    }
```

Since you are trying to get only one character, I think you can simply do as:

```
    if(length > 1){
        str = String.valueOf(str.charAt(length-2))
    }
```

Please make sure that `str` is not null otherwise put a null handling as well.

Comment: before getting the length you have to do null check

Comment: @Sura: You are right. I was making updates already but then I saw the `getWord(word);` is called on the splitted words so it should not be null, hence removed the null check but added a note in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're passing an empty string to *punctuationChar*.

Oh, and as you're just using the last character in str, it might be easier to convert it to a character.

Try this:

```
private boolean punctuationChar(String str) {
       if (str.length() > 0) {
           char lastChar = str.charAt(lastChar.length() - 1);

           // Returns true if the character is anything other than a letter, digit or space
           return !(Character.isLetterOrDigit(lastChar)) || Character.isWhitespace(lastChar);
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

I'm using isLetterOrDigit here, then inverting the result. So this method will return true for any string that contains anything other than A-Z, a-z or 0-9 at the end. I'm also counting spaces as not being punctuation.

This would be even easier if Oracle had thought of putting an "isPunctuation" method in!

The Character class in Java's pretty great for checks like this, definitely worth taking a look at the next time you're doing something similar.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Answer (score 0):

you can make that punctuation check easier:

```
private boolean punctuationChar(String str) {   
    if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {
        char c = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
        return c == '.' || c =='?'||c==',' || c =='!';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In general, try to avoid string operations as they are slow. and if you need to work with substrings or a string index, always make sure to be prepared for null, empty or short strings